# Can I control this Pololu VNH5019 Motor Driver Carrier with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pwm

Do you see any reason why I should not be able to control this [Pololu VNH5019 Motor Driver Carrier](https://www.pololu.com/product/1451) from a Raspberry Pi 2?

So far I own neither an Arduino nor a Raspberry Pi, but I would like to build a Pi based PCR machine.

I am a bit confused because this [very similar product](https://www.pololu.com/product/2507) is marketed for Arduino. My current very limited understanding is that the shield would nicely fit onto an Arduino and is probably supported by Arduino software libraries, but that I could also connect/solder the module "manually" to a Pi and hopefully find a way to send the necessary high/low/PWM signals from my (inexisting) Pi software.

Update 2015-04-09:

- We also received a reply [from a Pololu employee on their forum](http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=9737) (where I crossposted this question)
- And [another forum post where someone used a Raspberyy Pi to control a very similar Pololu motor driver](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/strange-effect-with-h-bridge-pwm-peltier-is-an-lc-filter-needed.30895/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very serious bit of kit.  You will certainly be able to control it from the Raspberry Pi or an Arduino.

On a side-note I use hobby motors which only use an amp or so.  For smaller motors you can get motor driver boards such as this [L9110S](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/261648975778) based one quite inexpensively.  For slightly larger motors an L298N based board may be suitable.

The Pi can provide PWM on all its gpios.  Generally this will be PWM similar to the Arduino, around 800Hz.  The later model Pis have two dedicated PWM channels which can provide 20kHz PWM.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library is one among several which you can use for PWM.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the kit and the good news! I first considered the "Adafruit 16-Channel PWM / Servo HAT" but then learned that the peltier heating/cooling element that we actually want to control with this will draw up to 6 A at 15 V.